# Symfony action with json response

Tags: php, json, http, symfony1, http-headers

I am using PHP + CURL to fetch data from a server in one of my actions. I then return the data as json from my action.

My action looks like this

```
public function executeTest(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $json = $this->getServerResponse();  // fetches data using CURL
    $this->getResponse()->setContentType('text/json');
    return $this->renderText($json);
}
```

When the above action is executed, the received json strng is (for example):

> { 'ok': true }1

If I change the last line in the action above to 
    return $this->renderText('foo');

the returned JSON is:

> { 'ok': true }foo

If I change the last line in the action above to 
    return $this->renderText('');

the returned JSON is:

> { 'ok': true }

My question are:

1. Why is the JSON data from the server being displayed together with the text in my renderText() method?
2. Where is the '1' appended to the JSON data coming from?
3. How do I resolve/fix this issue ?

I am running Symfony 1.4.x on Ubuntu

Comment: Well, I'm no expert, but I know renderText appends its passed value to any existing response content, rather than replacing it, so it almost looks as though the json is already there in your sfResponse's existing content, and you're appending $json to it, with $json not being what you expect it to be. We might need to see the source for getServerResponse() to figure out what's going on...

Comment: @Matt - I think you're on the right track. Looks like the `getServerResponse` function sets the response text and then returns true. This accounts for the `1` being appended (rendering true shows as a 1), the string foo and the empty string. All of which are being appended. @OP - You should really get `getServerResponse` to `return` the response rather than setting it and then returning true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, your problem lies in `getServerResponse()`. Can't help more without seeing that function.

Comment: yes actually - you're right. I am returning the return code from curl_exec (which is 1).